# "libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zlib, libz

I am getting this error as:

```
apt-get: error while loading shared librarie: libz.so.1:cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When trying:

```
sudo apt-get zlib1g
```

I'm using a Ubuntu 16.04 os and i can't log into the graphic interface, after booting I can only see a blinking underscore on the top left corner of the screen, so i pressed "alt+f4" to open a terminal session.

In my commands historical I found the command:

```
rm -rf zlib-1.6.37
```

(That command was executed from the root directory of my user.) And i don't know if that is the cause.

I do need some solution to thia problem as soon as possible please.

If you need some more info just ask for it, I will reply with the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've figured it out, it was quite simple, but i just got desperate

The solution was just to recreate the symlink that was damaged (libz.so.1) and that fixed the problem, now I have another issue, it seems like I'm connected to network but i don't have internet at all anyway that's for another question.

Thanks if somebody tried helping me, even if the question just have like 2 hours from posted.